# (Django )Django Restful Framework autocomplete search bar

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I'm trying to create a simple HTML search input based from rest framework API JSON file. so far I manage to GET the data from the JSON file. In console log the data i wanted is there but when I search for it in the search field it gives me this error :

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/nameList?term=a 404 (Not Found)
```

I try to convert it into string but still no different.

Here's my code :
HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<br>
<input id="name_search_tags" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</body>
<script>
    $.getJSON("list/?format=json", function (json) {
    console.log(json);

    $.each(json, function(key, val) {
        var nameList = [];
        var employee_name = val.employee_name;
        nameList.push(employee_name.toUpperCase());
        var string = nameList.toString();
        console.log(employee_name);
        console.log(nameList);
    });
    $("#name_search_tags").autocomplete({source: 'nameList'});
});
</script>
</html>
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class MyModel(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_name
```

serializer.py

```
from  rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        #fields = ('field 1','field 2')
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import *


    class MyModelList(APIView):
        def get(self, request):
                        #get all objects in model
            modelList = MyModel.objects.all()
            #convert to JSON                          #multiple objects in model
            serializers = MyModelSerializer(modelList, many=True)
            #return the serialize JSON data
            return Response(serializers.data)
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from search.views import *
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', search, name='search'),
    url(r'^list/', MyModelList.as_view(), name='list_view'),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "employee_name": "Rajiv"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "employee_name": "Izzat"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "employee_name": "Nagendra"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "employee_name": "Shawn"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "employee_name": "Jason"
    }
]
```

I appreciate everyone help. Thanks

Comment: Where is your backend code?

Comment: My apologies, I'll add right away

Comment: @M.Izzat I sorry but I'm really unable to see the auto complete part of it in the backend.. what mean is that there is code for filter and pagination. Otherwise at least change the title to reflect the question is more about jquery-ui autocomple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the autocomplete library but I assume `nameList` should be the variable holding your JSON source. It needs to be initialised before the `each` loop too, right now it is getting cleared as soon as you exit the `each` loop.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, apologies for the late reply, as you said I've declared nameList outside of the loop and it works. thanks for your help